# Close FB tab on mobile after share

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After FB share on mobile facebook redirect me to "m.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/feed" with white screen. On desktop all work fine.

Init:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
  FB.init({
    appId: '1009',
    status : true, 
    cookie : true, 
    xfbml  : true, 
    channelURL : window.location.origin + '/facebook_channel.html',
    oauth  : true, 
    version     : 'v2.0'
  });
});
```

Share:

```
FB.ui({
  description: 'text',
  display: 'popup',
  link: 'http://localhost:3000/sample',
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'text',
  picture: null,
  version: 'v2.0'
},
function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
      console.log(response);
  }
});
```

On desktop and mobile i get responce after share, but get redirect on mobile (iphone/ipad). I don't need redirect to any site after share so "**redirect_uri**" not suitable.

And i can't close main window after share, **self.close()** also not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

So, i changed method feed to share:

```
FB.ui({
  description: 'text',
  display: 'popup',
  href: 'http://example.com/post',
  method: 'share',
  name: 'text',
  picture: null,
  version: 'v2.2'
},
function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
      console.log(response);
  }
});
```

it's working but have some problems

1) you can't debug this on localhost, need deploy to some stage server

2) after share get this :

[image]

but this better than white screen after share

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing web app (site saved to Home Screen) for iOS and have the same problems. FB.ui doesn't work at all or have the described issue. Seems that the only way in this case is using redirect_url solution.